# Build relation between elasticsearch aggregators - Nested groupings

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to create nested groupings between fields.

Let us consider the example given below,

Documents:

```
 {
     "keyword": "abc",
     "country": "IN",
     "state": "TN",
     "city": "Chennai"
   },
   {
     "keyword": "abc",
     "country": "IN",
     "state": "TN",
     "city": "Trichy"
   },
   {
     "keyword": "abc",
     "country": "IN",
     "state": "KL",
     "city": "TVM"
   },
   {
     "keyword": "abc",
     "country": "US",
     "state": "Cal",
     "city": "California"
   }
```

Required output(Something like this):

```
   {
     "country": "IN",
     "TN": [
       "Chennai",
       "Trichy"
     ],
     "KL": [
       "TVM"
     ]
   },
   {
     "country": "US",
     "Cal": [
       "California"
     ]
   }
```

Query used:

```
 {
     "from": 0,
     "size": 1,
     "aggs": {
         "country": {
             "terms": {
                 "field": "country.keyword",
                 "size": 50000
             }
         },
         "state": {
             "terms": {
                 "field": "state.keyword",
                 "size": 50000
             }
         },
         "city": {
             "terms": {
                 "field": "city.keyword",
                 "size": 50000
             }
         }
     },
     "query": {
         "query_string": {
             "query": "(keyword:abc) "
         }
     }
 }
```

For this query I got separate bucket as output for city , state and country.

But what I need is city should be grouped under  state and state should be grouped under country.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query with aggregation should work for you

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(keyword:abc)"
    }
  }, 
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "country_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "state_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "state.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "city_agg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "city.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```